# Refined permission in a list

Tags: list, permissions, sharepoint-server

I'm having issue in a Sharepoint-based application. We are using a list as a news feed, and we want to give permission to users to write news in that feed.

Each news has a category: our problem is that we want persons of a certain group to only be able to create new entries with a given category.

We *must* keep everything in a single list. Basically, it comes down to this: how do we allow only given groups of users to use given values of a select box ?

Comment: From what you said, I understand that the news type is a choice field. Am I right ?

Comment: It is yes, and it would be best if it stayed that way, but it's not that important to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set permissions on objects other than web, list and items (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject), and site collection if you want to set site collection administrator(s).

You can do that programmatically by creating a custom new form and controlling which options to display to the current user regarding his permissions.

Comment: How would I create that custom form ? Is it a matter of editing the NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx file relevant to the list ?

Comment: You must have at least Visual Studio 2010 and create everything from scratch (I mean the list and the form). In the list params, you specify that you need to set the custom new form as the one that you developed and not the default one. You specify the logic in your custom form and voila.

There are a lot of tutorials on the net on how to do that, this is not a big deal :)